# how to mix trading signals for the same product?

Tags: cointegration, trading-systems

I have multiple trading signals developed using cointegration on the same stock using various correlated assets. Is there a mathematical way to combine them to achieve better entry/exit points and exploit more opportunities?

Thanks

Comment: Do your signals give you just a trade, or do your signals give you an optimal position (that you then need to trade into)?

Comment: It gives a trade's entry and exit points based on the z-score transformation of the error.